# What does "go back to waterfall" means?

Tags: word-meaning, sarcasm

One guy commented an article [Agile is Dead](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/agile-dead-matthew-kern)
 with(You can see the comment in the end of that article) :

> What insight! I guess you can go back to waterfall.
>
> Ken

So what does "go back to waterfall" here means?

Comment: [*Agile vs. Waterfall*](https://blog.udemy.com/agile-vs-waterfall/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*waterfall model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) is a step-by-step methodology for software engineering, often derided for being slow and inefficient. Agile methodology is largely a response to the shortcomings of the waterfall model, and the author of the article is either predicting or reporting the "death" of Agile. As I read it, the comment you're asking about is deeply sarcastic:

> What insight! I guess you can go back to waterfall.

The commenter actually means: "This is not very insightful at all. You're claiming to tell me about the end of a process that almost everybody in the business has adopted, but you haven't even proposed a replacement." By *you can go back to waterfall*, the commenter is pretending to take the article at face value and proposing the fairly ridiculous prospect of returning to a system that few people would prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I heard a lot about Agile these days, and I just forget the old waterfall model...

Comment: Does "go back to the waterfall" more correct in grammar than "go back to waterfall"?

Comment: @Sayakiss - Very interesting question. I'd probably include the "the"; however, it's okay either way. Whether it's included or omitted influences how I read the sentence. I'd read: _I guess you can go back to waterfall_ to mean, "I guess you can go back to waterfall [development]," while: _I guess you can go back to **the** waterfall"_ would mean, "I guess you can go back to the waterfall [methodology]."

Comment: @Sayakiss - No, "go back to the waterfall" doesn't really make sense here, because we're not talking about a specific waterfall.  *Waterfall* is more like a proper name here.